# Why does a fetched html file's script not execute?

Tags: javascript, html, fetch, es6-promise, fetch-api

I have been trying to work on this but to no progress came here about this issue.
The fetched html file's script fails to execute as you may see here it has script that should change the color of body when i fetch it but that does not happen however styles work fine.

Can anyone tell me why this isnt working?

Index HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <script>
    fetch("Onload.html")
      .then((response) => {
        return response.text();
      })
      .then((html) => {
        document.body.innerHTML = html;
      });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Fetched HTML

```
<p>HELLO WORLD!</p>
<script>
  document.body.style.backgroundColor='green'
</script>
```

Comment: Fetching content does not imply that embedded `<script>` tags will be evaluated; the browser does not even know what the content *is*.

Comment: @Pointy: but it's assigned to document.body.innerHTML... The issue is that innerHTML assignments by default don't execute script tags.

Comment: What should I use instead?

Comment: Replace your script tag by one that references an external js file.

Comment: jQuery has code that finds `<script>` tags in content and it explicitly executes them. That's pretty much all you can do; browsers simply do not evaluate `<script>` tags added to the DOM via `.innerHTML`.

Comment: @Pointy is that true for `script` tags with a valid `src` attribute as well?

Comment: @connexo I *think* so but I do not know for sure; [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#innerhtml0) seems to imply it but it's not very clear.

Comment: @connexo referncing an external js file via src in the fetched html does not work, I just checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without jquery!
Here is how to do it fellas

Index html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <script>
    fetch("Onload.html")
      .then((response) => {
        return response.text();
      })
      .then((html) => {
        document.body.innerHTML=html;
      });
    fetch('onload.js')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(txt => {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.innerHTML = txt;
        document.body.appendChild(script);
      });
    
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: For whatever reason you're doing this, make sure the script content is trustworthy, e.g. by applying a proper content-security policy. Otherwise this is dream land for XSS attackers.